# symfony2 - accessing private members of $_SESSION

Tags: php, symfony

I've been googling for hours for an answer and couldn't find one.
Since my website has a login system and I would like to use the data in the $_SESSION, I can't seem to get all the data I need, it's private and I need some kind of a function to get it, but without success.

Basically, I have a controller which I do:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->all()
```

which gives all the attributes in the $_SESSION, but I can't seem to be able to access the private attributes which I need since all() returns array.

How can I get these attributes?

Comment: What do you mean by private attributes?

Comment: @j0k, ["user":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>, I can't just do $session['user'], it's private

Comment: @Alon you can get user and token using security.context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the session through the [`Session`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session.html) class.

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->set('name', 'Adrien');
echo $session->get('name'); // Outputs "Adrien"
```